# Send keys with current username

Tags: batch-file, unified-service-desk

I'm trying to make a batch file that will open a specific site and type in the username.

I have the following code at the moment, but problem is that you have to type in user name yourself.

I was wondering if you could use %USERNAME% variable and convert each letter of it and type in automatically in the browser input window.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
start chrome "https://servicedesk.sa.gov.ge/"
rem the script only works if the application in question is the active window. Set a timer to wait for it to load!
timeout /t 3
rem use the tab key to move the cursor to the login and password inputs. Most htmls interact nicely with the tab key being pressed to access quick links.

rem now you can have it send the actual username/password to input box
%SendKeys% "{s}"
%SendKeys% "{o}"
%SendKeys% "{m}"
%SendKeys% "{e}"
%SendKeys% "{u}"
%SendKeys% "{s}"
%SendKeys% "{e}"
%SendKeys% "{.}"
%SendKeys% "{s}"


goto :EOF


@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

P.S. User name format in my case is taken from domain, for example: "otarashvili.e"

Comment: The easiest approach would probably be to pass `%USERNAME%` into your WScript code and iterate through that using a `FOR` loop and `MID$`. It _could_ be done in the batch-script, but would be more fiddly (e.g. one approach could be to repeatedly use`%USRNAM:~0,1%` to get the first character of `%USRNAM%`, and `SET "USRNAM=%USRNAM:~1%"` to strip that first character and repeat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to get it done with the following code:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off

rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
start chrome -new-window --incognito "https://servicedesk.sa.gov.ge/"
rem the script only works if the application in question is the active window. Set a timer to wait for it to load!
timeout /t 3
rem use the tab key to move the cursor to the login and password inputs. Most htmls interact nicely with the tab key being pressed to access quick links.

rem now you can have it send the actual username/password to input box
%SendKeys% "%USERNAME%"
%SendKeys% "{TAB}"

goto :EOF


@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```